# Delphi unicode porting : Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'AnsiChar' error with Win32 functions like CharToOEM?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I am trying to convert some old Delphi 7 code to Delphi 2010

```
function AnsiToDOS(S: String): String;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S));
  if S <> '' then begin
     CharToOEM(PChar(S), PChar(Result));
  end;
end;
```

I get the "Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'AnsiChar' " error at the line:

CharToOEM (external User32 function) found in

Windows.pas unit

Can I rewrite this AnsiToDos function somehow, or do I need to write my own CharToOEM routine?

Comment: The function [CharToOEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is [Banned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx) for microsoft instead use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @RRUZ Lots of those banned functions are perfectly reasonable to use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i prefer follow the MSDN recommendations (when is possible).

Comment: @RRUZ I agree in principle but these particular recommendations are highly debatable and there is a very large body of opinion contrary to this.

Comment: @RRUZ, look at the remarks: *"The classic C runtime, "n" functions are banned because they are so hard to call correctly. The authors have seen numerous errors calling these functions"*. Classic "guns kill people" i'd say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unicode Delphi, `CharToOem` maps to the Unicode version `CharToOemW` which has the following signature:

```
function CharToOem(Source: PWideChar; Dest: PAnsiChar): BOOL; stdcall;
```

So you need to supply an ANSI output buffer but your code provides a Unicode output buffer.

The natural conversion is to switch to an `AnsiString` return value. At the same time renamed the function as `StringToOem` to better reflect what it does.

```
function StringToOem(const S: String): AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S));
  if S <> '' then begin
    CharToOem(PChar(S), PAnsiChar(Result));
  end;
end;
```

An alternative would be to convert to OEM in place, but for this you need to pass in an ANSI string and call the ANSI version of the API call explicitly.

```
function AnsiStringToOem(const S: AnsiString): AnsiString;
begin
  Result := S;
  UniqueString(Result);
  if S <> '' then begin
    CharToOemA(PAnsiChar(Result), PAnsiChar(Result));
  end;
end;
```

I do have to comment that I am surprised to see the OEM character set still being actively used in the modern day. I thought it had gone the way of the dinosaurs!

Comment: If you're modifying strings in-place, don't forget to call `UniqueString` first.

Comment: Since when consoles became a dinosaurs?

Comment: @user539484 Since when were consoles restricted to OEM text?

Comment: Since Windows NT they do not. Yet even Microsoft stock tools are printing messages in (tada!) CP_OEMCP. You are not even using any characters outside Latin-1 set, i presume?

Comment: Indeed surprising: I just found out that `WSDLImp.dpr` in Delphi XE2 still uses it to convert `string` to OEM: `  CharToOEMA(PAnsiChar(AStr), PAnsiChar(AStr));`

Answer (score -1):

The most simple will be (in C++Builder):

```
typedef AnsiStringT<850> OEMString;
AnsiString (or String) aStr = L"my ansi text";
OEMString oStr = aStr;  // convert
cout << oStr.c_str() << endl;
```